# Some problems while uploading sprite to canvas in JS

Tags: javascript, canvas

`Hello! I have a problem with uploading an image to a canvas element in JS. I saved the image to some folder in my project, then I tried to upload it with the classic function, but then I faced that there is no errors, but my image is not displayed. Help me, please. All code and screenshots are further:
**Code:**
HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Game of Drones</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="S:\Coding\JS\UAVGame\CSS\style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="field" width="800px" height="600px"></canvas>
        <script src="S:\Coding\JS\UAVGame\JS\main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>`
```

CSS:

```css
#field {
    position: absolute;
    left: 22%;
    border: 9px grey double;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    background: rgb(8, 2, 63);
}
```

JS:

```js
let field = document.querySelector("#field");
let ctx = field.getContext("2d");

let UAV = new Image();
UAV.src = "S:/Coding/JS/UAVGame/OTHER/IMAGES/UAVBASED.png";

class Star {
    constructor(xCoord, yCoord, radius) {
        this.x = xCoord;
        this.y = yCoord;
        this.R = radius;
    }

    draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.R, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}

let stars = [];

function drawScene() {
    ctx.drawImage(UAV, 250, 250);
    
}

drawScene();
```

[Screen of project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiseO.png)

I don't know even what I have to try, because I use classic functions with a classic bundle of parameters, so I assume, that there is some magic, which makes me face that problem.`

Answer (score 0):

Try calling drawScene on image onload event like below

```
UAV.onload = function(){
   drawScene();
}
```

Also verify the path of image. I would suggest using absolute path like

```
UAV.src = "../OTHER/IMAGES/download.png";
```